# User doen't get redirected after login

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

After login is successful it stays on the login page with the user's info still in inputs, as I want it to redirect to previous location or home.. I don't know if I used useSearchParams the right way and if i should include them in the useEffect. "After login is successful it stays on the login page with the user's info still in inputs, as I want it to redirect to previous location or home.. I don't know if I used useSearchParams the right way and if i should include them in the useEffect" < jut to post the question

LoginScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Row, Col, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
//import products from "../../products";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { login } from "../../actions/UserActions";
import LoginForm from "../LoginForm";

function LoginScreen() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const redirect = searchParams.get(search.split("=")) || 1;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { error, loading, userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect);
      //searchParams.delete("userInfo");
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect, searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };
```

App.js:

```
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path="/cart">
              <Route path=":productid" element={<CartScreen />} />
              <Route index element={<CartScreen />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Container>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "efrontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.31"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using react router so you can use `useHistory` hook to handle this case as the following:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate(); // import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
    navigate('/your-route'); // redirects to /your-route
};
```

Comment: But history doesn't exist in react-router-dom v6 @mbistami

Comment: Updated answer for react-router-dom@v6

Comment: I tried that before, didn't work @mbistami

Comment: can you share your package.json on the question?

Comment: I just did, check it out @mbistami

Comment: if you're using `6.4.3` you need to remove '/' from `Route` path e.g =`<Route path='login'/>`

Comment: and in order for navigate to work define your routes as follows in the link https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router

Comment: Dman that looks more complicated, it says <BrowserRouter> do not support the data APIs. Wouldn't be easier to downgrade the version?? @mbistami

Comment: Agreed... the older version is stable and good too if you just need to handle routes.

Comment: v5 right? @mbistami

Comment: that's right! @v5

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misused the `useSearchParams` hook, or rather, accessing specific queryString parameters. The `searchParams` is a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object, so you should just get the queryString parameter by key.

Example:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (userInfo) {
    const redirect = searchParams.get("redirect");
    navigate(redirect || "/"); // <-- fallback to some defined page route
  }
}, [navigate, userInfo, searchParams]);
```

Comment: Thank you but I already fixed it by downgrading to v5 using match, history & location. Older version seems simpler to me @DrewReese